# Should all user information be encryped?

Tags: database

I've been learning about ways to keep databases for web applications more secure in School and one of the things mentioned was the encryption of data of the user's personal information. Now when I'm looking through examples of web systems I've noticed that it's normally just the password that is hashed, for obvious reasons, but should there be some sort of encryption when it comes storing a user's details such as their address? Is it safe to have these stored in plain text as long as you have measures in place to keep your database secure or should this be encrypted?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask but thought I would be able to get a good answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any Personally Identifiable Information (PII) should be encrypted in transit and at rest because it may be used for identity theft. There are recent instances of hackers getting into systems and stealing data that is then potentially sold on eg the Travelex data breach https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-51017852. Encrypting the data makes it valueless even if hackers do get into your network.

This is different to password hashing which is a one way mechanism to allow comparison of provided credentials against stored credentials without ever needing to convert the stored value to plaintext. PII data does normally need to be decrypted by the applications that use it.

Comment: Okay yeah that makes a lot of sense, saw a few conflicting things when looking up about it but what you've said makes sense, especially with the example you've given, thank you

Comment: Cool, enjoy your studies :-)